# Spark Streaming xml files

Tags: xml, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I have a requirement to process xml files streamed into a S3 folder. Currently, I have implemented it as follows.

First, Read files using Spark's fileStream

`val data = ssc.fileStream[LongWritable, Text, TextInputFormat]("s3://myfolder/",(t: org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path) => true, newFilesOnly = true, hadoopConf).map(_._2.toString())`

For each RDD, check if any file has been read

```
if (data.count() !=0)
```

Write the string to a new HDFS directory

```
data.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile(sdir);
```

Create a Dataframe reading from the above HDFS directory

```
val loaddata = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml").option("rowTag", "Trans").load(sdir)
```

Do some processing on Dataframe and save as JSON

```
loaddata.write.mode("append").json("s3://mybucket/somefolder")
```

Somehow, I feel that the above approach is very inefficient and frankly quite school boyish. 
Is there a better solution? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

A follow up question:
How to manipulate fields (not Columns) in a dataframe?
I have a vey complex nested xml and when I use the above described method, I am getting a Dataframe with 9 columns and 50 odd inner Struct arrays. That is fine except for the need to trim certain field names. Is there a way to achieve that without exploding the dataframe, as I need to construct the same structure again?

Answer (score 4):

If you use Spark 2.0 you may be able to make it work with structured streaming:

```
val inputDF = spark.readStream.format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
  .option("rowTag", "Trans")
  .load(path)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. My target env is EMR stack with Spark 2.0.1. I will try your suggestion on an EMR box.

Comment: pls vote-up/accept if you are okay with solution mentioned above.

Comment: `val inputDF = spark.readStream.format("com.databricks.spark.xml") .option("rowTag", "Trans") .load(path)` The above solution does not seem to work with spark 2.X

Comment: `UnsupportedOperationException: Data source xml does not support streamed reading.` Spark 3.5.1