# Spark xml dataframe

Tags: xml, apache-spark

A follow up question [to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40679817/spark-streaming-xml-files) : How to manipulate fields (not Columns) in a dataframe? I have a vey complex nested xml and when I use Databricks XML, I am getting a Dataframe with 9 columns and 50 odd inner Struct arrays. That is fine except for the need to trim certain field names. Is there a way to achieve that without exploding the dataframe, as I need to construct the same structure again?

Comment: "A follow up question???" pls review your posts before submit.

Comment: for ex you have xmlcolumn "xmlcol" of dataframe df `df.withColumn("xmlcol", sparkudfthatcallsscalafunctionmodify(df("xmlcol") ))` have you tried like this ?

Comment: Thanks a lot. The problem was not with the Columns, but with arrays of structs associated with the Columns. Found the solution through explode and construct. Thanks once again.